# How to install an app on sd card

Tags: motorola-droid-razr

I have some apps on my SD card and I want to install them on my phone but the Android or apk symbol does not appear on my phone...so how can I change the apps to apk so that I can install them.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the files have been stored as .zip files or without any extension. All you have to do is **rename** the files. Just download any *File Manager* from Play Store and rename the files.